# Image upload using vuejs and laravel through API is not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload image using vuejs and laravel through api. In vue.js I send the image info to laravel through api. but laravel do not get the info in correct format. that's why it shows an error. May be my procedure is not right.

Here is my codes

**Vue.js codes**

`

```
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="doctorImageSelected(event)">
    <button style="float: left;" class="ajmal-custom-btn" @click="goToUploadImage()">Upload</button>
```

`

`

```
       doctorImageSelected (event) {
            let image = event.target.files[0]
            this.image = image
            // console.log(this.image)
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
            reader.onload = event => {
                this.image = event.target.result

            }
        },
        goToUploadImage(){
            var self = this
            this.$http.post(apiDomain + 'api/savePatientProfilePicture',{pic: self.image,id: self.id})
                .then(response => {
                    if(response.status === 200){
                        console.log(response)
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    console.log(e)
                })
        }
```

`

**Laravel code**

`

```
  public function savePatientProfilePicture(Request $request){
    $pictureInfo = $request->pic;
    $picName = $request->id . $pictureInfo->getClientOriginalName();
    return $picName;
    $folder = "patinetImage/";
    $pictureInfo->move($folder,$picName);
    $picUrl = $folder.$picName;
    $user = new User();
    $patientPic = User::find($request->id);
    $patientPic->image = $picUrl;
    $patientPic->save();
  }
```

`

**Error**

> Call to a member function `getClientOriginalName()` on string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have added `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the request header.

After that, try this code

```
goToUploadImage(){
  var formData = new FormData;
  formData.append("pic", this.image, this.name);
  formData.append("id", this.id);


  var self = this
  this.$http.post(apiDomain + 'api/savePatientProfilePicture',formData, {
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      })
      .then(response => {
          if(response.status === 200){
              console.log(response)
          }
      }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e)
      })
}
```

Comment: where should I add content type? within post request?

Comment: I was updated the code for adding headers in the configs parameters

Comment: Your solution worked. but I used `headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }`

Comment: Now how can I retrieve the image from database and show it in vue js end by sending from laravel end?

Comment: Please post as new question for that

Comment: posted a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460740/how-to-show-image-in-vue-js-sending-image-info-from-laravel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get original name of the file, you need to call it on the UploadedFile object

```php
$pictureInfo = $request->file('pic');
$picName = $request->id . $pictureInfo->getClientOriginalName();
```

You can simplify this by using `ref` and `fetch` api

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="doctorImageSelected()" ref="doctorImage" />
<button style="float: left;" class="ajmal-custom-btn" @click="goToUploadImage()">Upload</button>
```

And in Javascript

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            image: {},
            id: 1 // Your ID and rest of data here
        };
    },
    methods: {
        doctorImageSelected(event) {
            this.image = this.$refs.doctorImage.files[0];
        },
        goToUploadImage() {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("pic", this.image);
            fd.append("id", this.id);
            fetch(`${apiDomain}api/savePatientProfilePicture`, {
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                    "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
                        .content
                },
                method: "POST",
                credentials: "same-origin",
                body: fd
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it returns `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null`

Comment: That means you're not correctly posting an image file

Comment: posting code is given above. Can you please check it?

Comment: Successfully done by the solution of @satmaxtdev. Can you please tell me how can I retrieve the image from database and show it in vue js end by sending from laravel end?

Comment: Too long for comments, post a new question